# Using Canon LIde 700F with xane over USB

Tags: usb, canon, sane, xsane

I know, I know, I should have never gotten a Canon to connect to a Linux box...

But the SANE supported-scanners doc said that the CanoScan 700F is supported "Good".  I took that to mean that it can scan at all but the highest res setting (9600 dpi).

But I haven't been able to actually scan anything except a low res preview.

I can see in /var/log/kern.log that the kernel sees it:

```
Jan 23 20:30:22 morpheus kernel: [269901.872029] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
Jan 23 20:30:22 morpheus kernel: [269902.005556] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=1907
Jan 23 20:30:22 morpheus kernel: [269902.005564] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 23 20:30:22 morpheus kernel: [269902.005569] usb 1-2: Product: CanoScan
Jan 23 20:30:22 morpheus kernel: [269902.005573] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Canon
```

This usually works:

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner 
[sudo] password for xxx: 

# sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
# result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
# scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Operation timed out
could not fetch string descriptor: Operation timed out
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9, product=0x1907) at libusb:001:014
```

This works only sometimes:

```
$ sudo scanimage -Lv

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different, ...
```

And when xsane *does* find the scanner and I try to scan something, it clicks a little, then just hangs.

Does anyone have experience getting this device to work on some version of LInux or should I just send it back and get an HP scanner?

Comment: Got the same problem here with my Canon LIDE 30.
That scanner used to work flawlessly under 12.04.
Under 14.04 sane-find-scanner says: found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x220e [CanoScan]) at libusb:003:003 but scanimage -L says: No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,... What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Canon Lide 700F runs plug and play under Ubuntu 13.10 (both 32bit and 64bit versions). I just use "Simple Scan" (not many features but it works with the basic ones). Thanks to the guys who helped with that.

Comment: Thanks.  Since I upgraded to Ubunto 13.10, all is working well.  :)